# Drawing a dendrogram based on a confusion matrix

Tags: clustering, distance, hierarchical-clustering, confusion-matrix, dendrogram

I have a simple 2D confusion matrix that I normalised for every true class. Now, what would be the best method to visualise this as a dendrogram?

I have seen hierarchical agglomerative clustering on the basis of the confusion matrix itself, and this is what I am currently doing. However, this feels a bit counter-intuitive, as such clustering methods would normally be applied to the raw data, instead of a confusion matrix resulting from *another* method working with that raw data. Is there a better way? For example by directly converting the confusion scores to a distance matrix with which a dendrogram could be drawn?